Network not improving with PyTorch CNN for Extended MNIST dataset
I've been looking all day at why this isnt improving, loss stays around 4.1 after the first couple batches.
Here's the dataset/
key = {'0':0,'1':1,'2':2,'3':3,'4':4,'5':5,'6':6,'7':7,'8':8,'9':9,'A':10,'B':11,'C':12,'D':13,'E':14,'F':15,'G':16,'H':17,'I':18,'J':19,'K':20,'L':21,'M':22,'N':23,'O':24,'P':25,
'Q':26,'R':27,'S':28,'T':29,'U':30,'V':31,'W':32,'X':33,'Y':34,'Z':35,'a':36,'b':37,'c':38,'d':39,'e':40,'f':41,'g':42,'h':43,'i':44,'j':45,'k':46,'l':47,'m':48,'n':49,'o':50,'p':51,
'q':52,'r':53,'s':54,'t':55,'u':56,'v':57,'w':58,'x':59,'y':60,'z':61}

# Hyperparams
learning_rate = 0.0001
batch_size = 32
epochs_num = 32

file = pd.read_csv('data/english.csv', header=0).values
filename_dict = {}
for line in file:
    # ex. ['Img/img001-002.png' '0'] .replace('Img/','')
    filename_dict[line[0]] = key[line[1]]


# Prepare data
image_tensor_list = [] # List of image tensors
filename_list = [] # List of file names
for line in file:
    filename = line[0] 
    filename_list.append(filename)
    img = cv2.imread("data/" + filename,0) # Grayscale
    img = img / 255.0  # Normalize to [0, 1]
    img_tensor = torch.tensor(img, dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(0)
    image_tensor_list.append(img_tensor)
    
# Split into to train and test
data_combined = list(zip(image_tensor_list, filename_list))
np.random.shuffle(data_combined)

# Separate shuffled data
image_tensor_list, filename_list = zip(*data_combined)

# 90% train
train_X = image_tensor_list[:int(len(image_tensor_list)*0.9)] 
train_y = []
for i in range(len(train_X)):
    filename = filename_list[i]
    train_y.append(filename_dict[filename])

# 10% test
test_X = image_tensor_list[int(len(image_tensor_list)*0.9)+1:-1] 
test_y = []
for i in range(len(test_X)):
    filename = filename_list[i]
    test_y.append(filename_dict[filename])

class dataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, x_tensor, y_tensor):
        self.x = x_tensor
        self.y = y_tensor
        
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return (self.x[index], self.y[index])
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.x)
    
train_data = dataset(train_X, train_y)
train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=train_data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, drop_last=True)

# Create the Model
class ShittyNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ShittyNet, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 16, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(16)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(32)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32*225*300, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 62)
        self._initialize_weights()
    
    def _initialize_weights(self):
        # Use Kaiming He initialization
        init.kaiming_uniform_(self.conv1.weight, nonlinearity='relu')
        init.kaiming_uniform_(self.conv2.weight, nonlinearity='relu')
        init.kaiming_uniform_(self.conv3.weight, nonlinearity='relu')
        init.kaiming_uniform_(self.fc1.weight, nonlinearity='relu')

        # Initialize biases with zeros
        init.zeros_(self.conv1.bias)
        init.zeros_(self.conv2.bias)
        init.zeros_(self.conv3.bias)
        init.zeros_(self.fc1.bias)
        init.zeros_(self.fc2.bias)


    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(x))))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.bn2(self.conv2(x))))
        
        # showTensor(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.softmax(self.fc2(x))
        return x
    
net = ShittyNet()
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=1e-5)

for epoch_num in range(epochs_num):
    print(f"Starting epoch {epoch_num+1}")
    for i, (imgs, labels) in tqdm(enumerate(train_loader), desc=f'Epoch {epoch_num}', total=len(train_loader)):
        labels = torch.tensor(labels, dtype=torch.long)
        # Forward
        output = net(imgs)
        loss = criterion(output, labels)
                
        # Backward 
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        if i % 2 == 0:
            os.system('clear')
            _, predicted = torch.max(output,1)
            print(f"Loss: {loss.item():.4f}\nPredicted: {predicted}\nReal: {labels}")

Ive experimented with simplifying the network, lowering the params, both dont do much. Add the code to initialize the weights with kaiming initialization, doesnt change loss. I also added a softmax activation to the last layer recently, which doesnt change anything in terms of results, but I was previously under the impression that there is automatically softmax applied with NNs in pytorch. Also added batch normalization which also made no change in the loss or how it changes.

You're using the wrong loss. Your model includes F.softmax, but nn.CrossEntropyLoss also includes a softmax. You are softmaxing twice.
